# Updating env variables in batch

Tags: variables, batch-file, if-statement

Here is how I try to update an evironment variable `JAVA_HOME`

```
if "%JAVA_HOME%" == "" (
    where java > java_path
    echo File contents is
    type java_path
    set /p JAVA_HOME=< java_path
    echo %JAVA_HOME:~0,-13%
    set JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME:~0,-13%
)
```

The output I get is

```
File contents is
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe
~0,-13
```

I am getting weird `~0,-13` instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7` which is expected because `where java` is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe`

Curiously, it succeeds if I remove `if "%JAVA_HOME%" = ""` condition.

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082): `echo !JAVA_HOME:~0,-13!` and `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` at the start of your script.